# How to create and mount a volume to a grafana docker image and use it to strore grafana dashbords and user information

Tags: docker, dockerfile, grafana, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have created a grafana docker image in aws fargate using aws ecs. The web app works well. However, I loose dashboards and user information anytime I restart the app. From my readings, this is because grafana image has no storage to keep information.

Following this link,https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/, I have added an EFS volume to the container.

Volume configuration : Root directory = / (the default one).

On the container name: STORAGE AND LOGGING session:.

Mount points: I have added the volume name.

Container path: /usr/app.

However, I still loose all dashboards ans user information on container restart.

Is there something that I am missing ?
Thank you for your support

Comment: Does this help? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/

Comment: Hello Onecricketeer, thank you for the shared link, I will try it, but do you know how I can do it using the dockerfile ?

Comment: You cant. You need to mount the volume at runtime

Comment: ok thank you, I will try your solution. I will give you feedback.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I tried you solution but it does not work. I still loose the user information and dashboards when I stop the container

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to show what you changed/tried.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making container have persistent storage one alternative could be to have a custom entrypoint script that downloads the dashboards and put them in `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/` (could be from s3) and then runs `/run.sh` this way you can keep your container stateless and not add any storage to it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure [custom database](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#database) (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL - AWS RDS/Aurora) instead of default file based SQLite DB. RDBs are better for concurrent access, so you can scale out better.

AWS offers also options for backups (e.g. automated snapshosts), so I would say DB is better solution than FS volumes (+ problems with FS permissions).